# Google Calendar API location swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, location, google-calendar-api

I am making an app for iPhone that wants to fetch some data from Google Calendar, and I am programming in Swift. The data I want to fetch is location, time, date and title of event. I have not been able to find out how one gets the location data from Google Calendar. I know it exist in the pods to GoogleClientForRest/Calendar, but I am not able to access it. I thought I could access it from GTLRCalendar_Event, but it does available under this.

Xcode Error:

[image: How it looks in Xcode]

Can somebody please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using

`GTLRCalendar_Event.location`

This is the class itself, not an instance of it, so it has no data.

You need to use the instantiated object to fetch the properties.

Having a quick scan over the SDK you are using when you fetch a list of calendar entries it looks like you get a list of type `[GTLRCalendar_CalendarListEntry]` this type also has a location property which it looks like you could use.

If you could show more of your code I could give you a more specific answer as I haven't used this SDK in a while

Comment: This is how I in the code fetch the other data:
´code´ let query = GTLRCalendarQuery_EventsList.query(withCalendarId: "primary")
query.maxResults = 10
query.timeMin = GTLRDateTime(date: Date())
query.singleEvents = true
query.orderBy = kGTLRCalendarOrderByStartTime

Comment: I can't access the location from [GTLRCalendar_CalendarListEntry] is just say it does not have any member location.